# React: TypeError: _this2.props.people is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I use React (in context of Rails with react_on_rails gem) and I'm getting the error message:

TypeError: _this2.props.people is undefined

```
import React from 'react';

var people = [
  {
      "name": "Sister Altenwerth",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ryandownie/128.jpg",
      "id": 3
  }
]

class Card extends React.Component {

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
              <img src={this.props.avatar} alt=""/>
              <div></div>
              <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Delete Me</button>
          </div>
      )
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {

  deletePerson(person) {
      this.state.people.splice(this.state.people.indexOf(person), 1);

      this.setState({people: this.state.people});
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        people: this.props.people.splice(0)
      }
  }

  render() {
      var that = this;
      return (
          <div>
              {this.state.people.map(function (person) {
                  return (
                      <Card key={person.id} onClick={that.deletePerson.bind(null, person)} name={person.name} avatar={person.avatar}></Card>
                  )
              }, this)}
          </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Foo
```

I've gone through the react docs and I still can't figure out, where the problem is with the code. Maybe it's related to react_on_rails gem.

The original code is using React.createClass() function and I converted it to use ES6 class extends Syntax and constructor instead of getInitialState().

Comment: You have to declare your initial state people in your constructor like this : `this.state = { people }` to get the array you declare at the beginning of your file. Btw this is wrongly flagged at duplicate because it's not a binding issue(for now). There's a lot of other issues in your code but i can't correct all of them in a comment.

Comment: can you provide this comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: I can't because your post is flagged as a duplicate, but thanks anyway for that.